# Explicitly Set Core Data Objects Still Carry Nil Value

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data

Working through Paul Hudson's ["100 Days of SwiftUI"](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui/61) and I'm having an issue where data from a FetchRequest features nil values for some properties even after they've been set explicity.

The idea is fire off a request for a .json file, download it, and then parse it into some CoreData objects.

Here's the output:
[image]

And clicking on the top "Unknown" yields:
[image]

Now for some code:

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var cachedUsers: FetchedResults<CachedUser>
    @State private var users = [User]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(cachedUsers) { cachedUser in
                
                NavigationLink {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Name: \(cachedUser.unwrappedName)")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Section {
                            Text("Email:")
                            Text(cachedUser.uEmail)
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            
                            Text("Company")
                            Text(cachedUser.uCompany)
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            
                            Text("Address:")
                            Text(cachedUser.uAddress)
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        } header: {
                            Text("Contact")
                                .font(.title)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                } label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("\(cachedUser.unwrappedName)")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(cachedUser.isActive ? .white : .red)
                    }
                }
            }
            .task {
                if cachedUsers.isEmpty {
                    do {
                        if let retrievedUsers = try await loadData() {
                            users = retrievedUsers
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                    await MainActor.run {
                        saveToCoreData(users: users)                        
                    }
                }
                printCache()
            }
           .navigationTitle("Users")
           .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
    
    func loadData() async throws -> [User]? {
        
        if users.isEmpty {
            
            let targetURL = "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json"
            guard let url = URL(string: targetURL) else {
                print("Bad URL. No biscuit.")
                return users
            }
            
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                users = try decoder.decode([User].self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return users
    }
    
    func saveToCoreData(users: [User]){
        
        for user in users {
            
            let cd = CachedUser(context: moc)
            cd.about = user.about
            cd.address = user.address
            cd.age = Int16(user.age)
            cd.company = user.company
            cd.email = user.email
            cd.id = user.id
            cd.isActive = user.isActive
            cd.name = user.name
            cd.registered = user.registered
            
            for friend in user.friends {
                let cf = CachedFriend(context: moc)
                cf.id = friend.id
                cf.name = friend.name
                cd.addToFriend(cf)
            }
            
            do {
                if moc.hasChanges {
                    try moc.save()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func printCache() {
        for cachedUser in cachedUsers {
            print("Name: \(cachedUser.unwrappedName) | \(cachedUser.uUUID) ")
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

**User**

```
import Foundation

struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id, isActive, name, age, company, email, address, about, registered, tags, friends
    }
    
    var id = UUID()
    var isActive: Bool = false
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int16 = 20
    var company: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var about: String = ""
    var registered: Date = Date.now
    var tags: [String] = []
    var friends: [Friend] = []
    
    init() { }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(isActive, forKey: .isActive)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(age, forKey: .age)
        try container.encode(company, forKey: .company)
        try container.encode(email, forKey: .email)
        try container.encode(address, forKey: .address)
        try container.encode(about,forKey: .about)
        try container.encode(registered,forKey: .registered)
        try container.encode(tags, forKey: .tags)
        try container.encode(friends, forKey: .friends)
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
        isActive = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isActive)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        
        age = try container.decode(Int16.self, forKey: .age)
        company = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .company)
        
        email = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
        address = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
        about = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .about)
        registered = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .registered)
        
        tags = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .tags)
        friends = try container.decode([Friend].self, forKey: .friends)
    }
}


class UserData: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var user = User()
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case user
    }
    
    init() { }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        try container.encode(user, forKey: .user)
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        user = try container.decode(User.self, forKey: .user)
    }
}
```

NOTE: The CachedUser extension handles name and email (for example) identically.

**Core Data Entity and printCache() Result Screenshot**
[image]

It doesn't make any sense at all how printCache (which is going through the FetchResults cachedUsers objects) can print names, but then the minute I go through that exact same fetch object *only the names* don't carry through ("Unknown" displays as a result of nil coelescing) , but all the other data (About section, email, company, address) somehow does. The CachedFriend names don't, but I suspect that's the same issue I'm having with the CachedUser object just downstream.

Comment: That is a lot of code, would it be possible to create a simple example with minimum code to reproduce your issue? That way you can isolate the problem instead of posting the entire app

Comment: `public var uUUID: UUID { id ?? UUID() }`, do you ever actually set the `id` property on your `CachedUser` objects?

Comment: I thought so - at least that's what I was trying to do in the User decode function. It's called in ContentView loadData().

I replaced the reference to UserDetailView with a simpler version and took out the CachedUser extension and all the Friends stuff.  CachedUser handles 'name' and 'email' (for example) identically, though name isn't making it to the output while email is (as is 'company', 'address', etc.) - so the problem doesn't seem to be there. The Friends stuff is separate, but related issue so I can understand wanting to omit it from the question. Hope that helps clear things up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered that the users are getting added after all. I realized that when I went to scroll on all my 'Unknowns' if I scrolled down far enough (1000+ rows) I'd start to see names. I have no idea what I did, but at one point I was adding to CoreData without regard to replacement.

In the end I had to tweak loadData() a little to get this working and then delete a bunch of garbage data that had gone in during the process of development. The ContentView was the only place I was doing it wrong. All the other code was fine.

**UPDATED ContentView (Working) **

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var cachedUsers: FetchedResults<CachedUser>
    @State private var users = [User]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(cachedUsers) { cachedUser in
                    NavigationLink {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
    
                             
                            //... same as above


                            } header: {
                                Text("Contact")
                                    .font(.title)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text("\(cachedUser.uName)")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .foregroundColor(cachedUser.isActive ? .white : .red)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeUser)
            }
            .task {
              await loadData()
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Users")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
        
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
    
    func removeUser(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            
            //this hack helped me tremendously in cleaning up the CoreData object. I was adding 200 to the index at one point.
            //for i in index...index + 10{
                let user = cachedUsers[index]
                moc.delete(user)
                
                do {
                    try moc.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            //}
        }
        
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        if cachedUsers.isEmpty {
            let targetURL = "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json"
            guard let url = URL(string: targetURL) else {
                print("Bad URL. No biscuit.")
                return
            }
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                users = try decoder.decode([User].self, from: data)
                await MainActor.run {
                    saveToCoreData(users: users)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveToCoreData(users: [User]){
        
        for user in users {
            
            let cd = CachedUser(context: moc)
            cd.about = user.about
            cd.address = user.address
            cd.age = Int16(user.age)
            cd.company = user.company
            cd.email = user.email
            cd.id = user.id
            cd.isActive = user.isActive
            cd.name = user.name
            cd.registered = user.registered
            
            for friend in user.friends {
                let cf = CachedFriend(context: moc)
                cf.id = friend.id
                cf.name = friend.name
                cd.addToFriend(cf)
            }
            
            do {
                if moc.hasChanges {
                    try moc.save()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }    
}
```